# How do I grab a field from a referenced item in views?

Tags: views, 9

I currently have a view block called `Offerings` that shows up on all my `Course` content-type pages that display all the offerings for the said course. These offerings are their own content type called `Course Offerings`. The `Course Offerings` content type has a `field_course_reference` field so to know which `Course` the offering is for. In order for it to show the proper courses on my view, I have a Contextual Filter set up that references the `field_course_reference` and have it set to "Provide default value" of type "Content ID from URL". My `Course` content-type also has an Entity Reference taxonomy field called `field_course_category`.

What I'm trying to do from the `Offerings` view is grab the `field_course_category` that lives in the `Course` content-type in which the view is being displayed on. I've tried adding every type of relationship and played around with a bunch of settings but no matter what I choose, the field I create remains empty and doesn't seem to grab the taxonomy term that I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any idea on how to go about doing that?

---

I'll try to draw the structure out a bit below as well to hopefully clear up any misunderstandings.

**Content Types:**

- Course

  - `field_course_category`
- Course Offerings

  - `field_course_reference`

**View Block:**

- Offerings

  - This view lists all the "Course Offerings" content types on the "Course" pages using the `field_course_reference` contextual filter using "Content ID from URL".
  - Trying to also get the value of `field_course_category` on this view so that I can use some conditional logic.

Let me know if anything else is needed to clarify. Again, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up figuring this out myself after digging deeper into relationships so I'm just going to post what I did in case anyone else ever comes into a similar situation.

I had to create 3 new relationships in this order:

1. **`field_course_reference:content`** - This appeared in my "Course Offerings" content type
2. **Taxonomy term referenced from `field_course_category`** - This appeared in my "Course" content type. I had to use #1 above as a relationship.
3. **Content using `field_course_category`** - Relate each content with a `field_course_category` set to the taxonomy term. This had to use #2 above as a relationship.

Then, I went over to my fields and selected the Category of "Taxonomy term" and chose **Name**. I selected the relationship of `field_course_category: Taxonomy term` and the data that I needed was now displayed properly.